# How to disable logging for specific method call in code with Log4net

Tags: log4net, log4net-filter

I'm facing a trouble with spammed log while calling the method from one of my referenced assemblies.

Is there a good way to disable Log4net logging for one specific method call (in code where I call my method).

Note: I do not want to disable logging at all, just in one specific place for one specific method call.

Thanks in advance,
Yurii

Comment: If the message has the same text every time (or at least matches a particular pattern), you can add a `StringMatchFilter` to your appender with `acceptOnMatch` set to `false`. There's also a `LoggerMatchFilter` if you can narrow it down to a logger name. If the method could log anything you've got a problem: there are no filters to filter on a specific stack trace, and while you could write something like that, walking the stack every time would be very expensive. I suppose you could write a filter that you could toggle on exactly at the place where you need it, but that's iffy with threads.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to  play with StringMatchFilter.